# BitLocker & Dual boot

Tags: grub, bitlocker

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my machine alongside Windows 10 with BitLocker encryption enabled (to be frank I didn't even know such encryption is enabled by default). This messed things up. I neither have a recovery key nor a Microsoft account. Is it possible to fix it by removing Ubuntu together with its bootloader?

Comment: Without the recovery key, your situation has no solution, as you required the recover key to suspend or disable BItLocker at this point.

Comment: You can remove Ubuntu and try to restore the original bootloader using Windows 10 installer medium, but the chance is high that the new bootloader or config is slightly different - a single bit is enough - which means the TPM sealed key can still not be used like it is at the moment. The interesting part in my opinion is how you managed to install Ubuntu on a dual boot system with encrypted Windows. Usually Ubuntu detects Bit locker and refuses installation (I tried this once with Ubuntu 20.04).

Comment: @Robert I can't recall that the Ubuntu installer warned me about anything.

Comment: @Robert It should always be possible to boot Windows directly (UEFI > Boot) exactly as thoroughly describe in the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

If Secure Boot was originally enabled for Windows, make sure it's still enabled.

Then select Windows **from the firmware boot menu** – not from the Ubuntu GRUB menu. Do not enter the firmware setup screen either, just press F11 or F12 (or other appropriate key) to access the boot menu and choose "Windows Boot Manager" from there.

The default BitLocker PCR binding profile for Secure Boot (0,7,11) relies on information about what SB signing certificates were involved in the boot process, i.e. it requires all .efi files to be signed by Microsoft's "Windows" certificate, which Ubuntu's bootloader is not. If you go through GRUB before selecting Windows, that causes the TPM boot log to be different and the BitLocker key can't be unsealed.

(Additionally, PCR 7 tracks which certificates were *imported* into Secure Boot's "trusted" and "revoked" `db` and `dbx` lists, but in your case those probably didn't change.)

The non-Secure Boot profile (0,2,4,11) instead matches the specific hashes of each .efi binary that has been executed since power-on, so if e.g. GRUB is run before Windows Boot Manager, that once again causes differences in the TPM's event log.

The mere *presence* of Ubuntu in the boot menu shouldn't cause problems though (that's PCR 1, which is not part of either profile), as long as the Windows boot doesn't go through it.

Comment: thanks for your input! I see I have to educate myself a bit before I tackle it again ;)